# Middleman Frontmatter YAML list

Tags: ruby, yaml, middleman

I just want to make a simple each loop in my Middleman helper, datas are stored in my page'Frontmatter like this :

```
dir:
  - test
  - test2
```

So in my helper, I try to write my loop :

```
def translate_directory
  current_page.data.dir.each do |dir|
    dir
  end
end
```

call my method in my page

```
<%= translate_directory %>
```

and this is what's display :

```
["test", "test2"]
```

---

But now, if I make the same loop in my page, write with ERB syntax :

```
<% current_page.data.dir.each do |x| %>
  <%= x %>
<% end %>
```

the exit is the following

```
test test2
```

separated in two strings, so exactly what I want.

---

**EDIT :** when I `puts` the helper'method, it display the two strings in two lines, so in two separated strings. Don't understand why it appear as an array on my browser.

---

**EDIT 2 :** a little thing I forgot, I want to translate each word with I18n.translate, like this :

```
def path_translate
  current_page.data.dir.each { |dir| t("paths.#{dir}", locale: lang) }
end
```

but i can't because the each method doesn't work so I18n can't translate each word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. Using .map instead of .each fix the problem, then use .join makes the array a big string.

Answer (score 1):

Because your helper is returning an array not a interpolated string like the ERB template is doing. Try the following for your helper:

```
def translate_directory
  current_page.data.dir.join(' ')
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to precise why I wan't multiple strings. I've just add it (edit 2). So join method to get one big string doesn't work anymore.